# Почему не работает геолокация в safari и android?

Tags: javascript, геолокация, safari

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код js:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {      
o.lon = position.coords.longitude;    
o.lat = position.coords.latitude;

console.log("lon = " + o.lon); ...
```

Проблема в том, что браузер Safari(602.1) даже не запрашивает разрешение на получение гео данных. В консоль ничего не выводится. Пробую на iphone 5s, также пробовал в последней версии Chrome на android'e.

Comment: Если нужен полный код, то можете посмотреть тут: https://codepen.io/letsdoit/pen/rGeKOE?editors=1001

Answer (score 0):

В общем все оказалось довольно прозаично. В настройках телефона была заблочена функция геолокации для браузера safari.